# Docker-compose networking, access host port from container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: dash
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        webpackVersion: 2.2.1
        nodeVersion: "6.x"
    ports:
      - "3036:3036"
    links:
      - mongodb:dbhost
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mongodb
```

Right now `web` has access to `mongodb` container where I keep app configs. But I also need to be able access port 3306 on my local machine where I'm running docker-compose, from `web`.

I tried to follow the documentation, but I'm new in docker so it looks pretty complicated for me, how to use networking in docker-compose.

If any one can help me to understand this I'll be really grateful!

Comment: Are you running Linux, Windows or Mac?

Comment: now on mac, but production will be on linux

Comment: And what is the command you are using to run the docker compose?

Comment: docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d

Comment: Are you trying to access 3306 or 3036?

Comment: 3306 [mySQL] on the machine where I'm running docker, 3036 is `web` app public port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found only one way to open all host ports, is to use `network_mode: host`
it should be also possible by using [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) but in my case first solution was enough.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: dash
    network_mode: host
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        webpackVersion: 2.2.1
        nodeVersion: "6.x"
    ports:
      - "3036:3036"
    links:
      - mongodb:dbhost
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mongodb
```

`network_mode: host` won't work on mac, you should run docker in VB